# Add a new row when sum of rows reaches value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

How would I go about adding a new row beneath the value where max 48 in the below example is reached in Google Sheets?

[image: Screenshot attached:]

Edit: Demo Google Sheet added: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jKX-AOfbFAEvks_Q8P8jegFek4ZocZJY113TfaY6jcQ/edit#gid=2041258691

Comment: can you provide some explanation of what are you after with maybe some example? it's hard to tell what you need where.

Comment: @player0, Sure have added a new sheet in the example to show what I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(A5:A<>"", 
 "♦"&A5:A&"♠"&B5:B&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5:A, REGEXREPLACE(""&SORTN(FILTER({A5:A, 
 IF(LEN(A5:A), QUERY(ROUNDUP((ROUND(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B5:B)
 <= TRANSPOSE(ROW(B5:B)))*B5:B), SIGN(B5:B))*5/48, 1))-1), "offset 1", 0), )}, 
 MOD(IF(LEN(A5:A), QUERY(ROUNDUP((ROUND(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B5:B)
 <= TRANSPOSE(ROW(B5:B)))*B5:B), SIGN(B5:B))*5/48, 1))-1), "offset 1", 0), ), 5)=0, 
 IF(LEN(A5:A), QUERY(ROUNDUP((ROUND(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B5:B)
 <= TRANSPOSE(ROW(B5:B)))*B5:B), SIGN(B5:B))*5/48, 1))-1), "offset 1", 0), )<>0), 
 999^99, 2, 2, 1), "^\d+", "♦♥"), 2, 0)), ),,999^99), "♦")), "♠♥"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is great, how could it be extended to scale to beyond 35 rows?

Comment: by adding more rows/items